# Configuración estilos en pycharm

Tags: python, configuración, pycharm

Recientemente he conseguido la versión profesional de pycharm, el ide de JetBrains.

Al cambiar el tema por defecto y tocar un par de parámetros para que me muestre un par de detalles como a mi me gustan, de repente ha ocurrido algo que me ha dejado totalmente despistado y que me está 'matando'.

En algunos archivos el background se ha puesto de color rojo y me destroza la vista. Alguien sabe a que se puede deber?

Muchas gracias de antemano, adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que haya bugs con los estilos en la versión más reciente. Yo mismo tengo que cargar mi propio color scheme cada vez que inicio el programa porque no me lo guarda (es frustrante). Esto solo me ocurre desde la última versión 2018.3

Comment: Cierto!! Debe ser eso ya que la desinstalación y reinstalación solucionó el problema. La respuesta al por qué sigue siendo un misterio, pero al menos el problema se solucionó.
Gracias por el comentario @Saelyth

Comment: ¿se te ha solucionado reinstalando? Entonces haré lo mismo, gracias por comentarlo.

Comment: De momento sí @Saelyth, si veo alguna cosa rara o vuelve el problema a presentarse, volveré a escribir por aquí!